# Updating Linking Tables without Models (Phoenix)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a simple many-to-many relationship that I would like to be able to update easily.

I create two schemas which have primary tables and are joined by a linking table with no schema.

Migrations

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end

  def change do
    create table(:organizations) do
      add :orgname, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end

  def change do
    create table(:users_organizations, primary_key: false) do
      add :user_id, references(:users), null: false
      add :organization_id, references(:organizations), null: false
      timestamps()
    end
    create index(:users_organizations, [:user_id])
    create index(:users_organizations, [:organization_id])
    create index(:users_organizations, [:user_id, :organization_id], unique: true)
  end
end
```

---

Models

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    many_to_many :organizations, MyApp.Accounts.Organization, join_through: "users_organizations"
    timestamps()
  end

  schema "organizations" do
    field :orgname, :string
    many_to_many :users, MyApp.Accounts.User, join_through: "users_organizations"
    timestamps()
  end
```

---

Seeds

```
alias MyApp.Repo
alias MyApp.Accounts.User
alias MyApp.Accounts.Organization

Repo.insert!(%User{ name: "Aaron"} )
Repo.insert!(%User{ name: "Bob"} )
Repo.insert!(%User{ name: "Calvin"} )

Repo.insert!(%Organization{ orgname: "Airport"} )
Repo.insert!(%Organization{ orgname: "Brokerage"} )
Repo.insert!(%Organization{ orgname: "College"} )
```

---

Without resorting to raw queries, is it possible to write ecto commands that add Aaron and Bob to the Airport, then another that removes Bob from the Airport in this scenario?  This would need to insert a record into table `users_organizations` without the use of a schema such as `MyApp.Accounts.UsersOrganizations`.

If not, is it always advisable that a schema accompanies a linking table?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question correctly but I see absolutely no problem to wrap those actions into a transaction and run them in any sequence you need, without any raw queries

Comment: @JustMichael How would I update the linking table in the transaction?  I need to insert a record into `users_organizations`, but there is no schema for `MyApp.Accounts.UsersOrganizations`.

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3 This function can accept table name instead of schema so maybe that will do the trick